# Rest can MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA be used with @Produces

Tags: java, arrays, rest, media-type

I have a rest service which produces the object of this format :

FileDetailsObject{

byte[] data;
String position_of_logo;
String username;

}

Is there a way to accomplish this in rest?

If it was just byte[] , I could use the Octet_Stream. But I need to return an object with a byte[].

I read about MediaType. Multipart_Form_Data but as far as I understand it seems to be associated with @Consumes where you can send it to  a service post request.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multipart response like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204061/2587435)<sup>1</sup> or you can base64 the byte array using an automatic converter like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300638/2587435). On deciding which way to go, I would say the deciding factor would be who are the clients. Some clients can't handle multipart responses, but pretty much all languages have some kind of base64 conversion method.

---

<sub>1. This solution is Jersey specific. You didn't specify which JAX-RS implementation you are using.</sub>